# Bundle ES6 files without transpilation

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I searched a lot before posting this and was, honestly, shocked to not find a solution. I want to bundle my ES6 files into a single module but, since ES6 is supported by the browser I use for testing, don't actually want to transpile anything. I can't figure out how to do it. I'm using webpack and saw a suggestion to simply omit the presets and plugins in my .babelrc file, but I get an error saying an object spread line has an unexpected token (the spread operator). How do I simply traverse the import/export paths to bundle the code but leave it as ES6? Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure that the browser you are using have support for the spread operator? take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), it mentions which browsers actually support it and has some examples you can try without the `webpack` overhead so you could be sure where your problem is

Comment: `object spread` isn't ES6! Hence the problem. You can use Rollup but it will [have problems with object spread too](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1613) - because it isn't spec-compliant. You still need Babel to fix object spreads at least.

Comment: estus, I know object spread isn't ES6, but my goal is just to concatenate all my files without transpiling. Ignore the ES6 part :) I'm gonna give @Prashant's solution a try. Thanks for the response, though! Yoav, thank you as well :) I'm positive my browser supports it:
`const obj = { a:4, b: 2 }`
`const other = { ...obj, c: 3 }`
`other // {a: 4, b: 2, c: 3}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [babel-preset-env](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env)

And, target transpilation for your specific browser. If that browser supports all `ES6` features, then it won't be transpiled down to `ES5`.

E.g.

Your `.babelrc` could look like

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "chrome": 60
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

You can also target multiple browsers so that your code works everywhere.

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "chrome": 60,
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari 7"]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was surprisingly a lot easier than I'd expected :)

Answer (score 0):

[rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org) is an ES6 module bundler.