# Make JavaScript bundle without transpilation of latest(not ES6) features

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I want to make a bundle without transpilation and also want to use latest features supported by browsers even if it's not ES6 yet(for example Chrome supports spread operator for objects). And yes, I'm sure that all clients use only latest versions of browsers.
I have spent couple of days in searching and didn't find enything except this: [Bundle ES6 files without transpilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46627770/bundle-es6-files-without-transpilation)
But this doesn't help me.
I tried to use `babel-preset-env` and `Chrome 64` as target but "object spread" was transpilled anyway.

```
let o1 = {
    f1: 1
};

let o2 = { ...o1,
    f2: 2
};
```

transpilled to

```
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function($) {function _objectSpread(target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i] != null ? arguments[i] : {}; var ownKeys = Object.keys(source); if (typeof Object.getOwnPropertySymbols === 'function') { ownKeys = ownKeys.concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source).filter(function (sym) { return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, sym).enumerable; })); } ownKeys.forEach(function (key) { _defineProperty(target, key, source[key]); }); } return target; }
var o1 = {
    f1: 1
};

var o2 = _objectSpread({}, o1, {
    f2: 2
});
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: browserify maybe?

Comment: How are you expecting to "use the latest features supported by browsers" and not transpile down to something each browser can understand? You would have to do a check if certain features exist and then code around them anyway. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: This seems like a "it hurts when I hit myself" problem. If you don't want to transpile, don't do any transpilation in your build process.

Comment: @zfrisch Just imagine(for simplification) that we are speaking only about object spread function and only about Chrome latest version

Comment: @Pointy OK, sounds reasonable. Could you please give me example of `webpack.config.js` that can help me to do it?